# How to find points of intersection between ellipse and line?

Tags: java, geometry, coordinates

I'm completely stuck.
I have an ellipse, and a line. Line is set by two points, ellipse - by bottom-left and top-right corners. I have to find their points of intersection, using java.
I tried to solve an equation system:

```
(1) y = kx + m;
x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1;
```

but I could't make things work properly. I assume it's because of java's coordinate system, but it also may be my own mistake somewherem beacuse I'm confused with it.

Is there any better way to find points of intersection and, if not, how can I get them properly?

Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
double r1 = in_y2-in_y;
double r2 = in_x2-in_x;
double k = r1/r2;
double m = in_y2 - k*in_x2;
double a =  Math.abs((double)x2 - (double)x)/2;
double b =  Math.abs((double)y2 - (double)y)/2;

double A1 = 1/(a*a) + (k*k)/(b*b);
double B1 = (2*k*m)/b*b;
double C1 = (m*m)/(b*b);
double D = Math.sqrt(B1*B1 - 4*A1*C1);
double ex1 = (-B1 + D/(2*A1));
double ey1 = k*ex1 + m;
double ex2 = (-B1 - D/(2*A1));
double ey2 = k*ex2 + m;
```

Comment: You need a set of equations and then you need to solve them. It seems you are doing that, so what exactly is the problem you are facing? It is not very clear from your post. Are you doing the calculations usings ints or doubles?

Comment: Do you expect Java to solve your equations for you? That's done by pen and paper. In Java you'll write the **solution** not the **equations**.

Comment: What I see now is that m in the first equation gets unbelivevably big (like, 1500). And that ruins all other equations, so that intersections points are 12000 higher, which is obviosly incorrect.
My guess it's because of inverted Y-Axis, but I don't really know.
I can paste the code, that I'm trying to make work, if that would help.

Comment: Marko, I think, in Java you write the algorithm, by wich computer can return correct answer. I know how to solve these equations, but I don't know how to make Java coordinate system deal with decart coordinate system.

Comment: It would be really helpful. At the moment you are just telling us that you have a problem and need help, but not giving us information so we can help!

Comment: You don't need an **algorithm** to solve this system, it's got a simple direct solution in closed form. You should write Java code only to calculate the concrete values from that closed form. BTW Are you trying to model nearly vertical lines? You should use the implicit line form which doesn't suffer from `k` escaping to infinity for vertical lines.

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Ax+%2B+By+%3D+C%3B+x%5E2%2Fa%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%2Fb%5E2+%3D+1) is what I had in mind when I said "use implicit line equation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably no longer relevant to the original problem owner, but since I encountered the same question, let me present my answer.

There are three mistakes in the original computation that I can see: (i) the one pointed out by @mprivat, (ii) the bracketing in the assignment to `B1` which should instead be

```
double B1 = (2*k*m)/(b*b);
```

and (iii) a more fundamental one: the presented computation does not correct for the origin of the ellipse. Since the ellipse is defined by itse circumscribing bounds, there is no guarantee that it is centered on `(0,0)`.

Let's call the center `(cx,cy)`, then the equation for the ellipse becomes

```
(x-cx)^2/a^2 + (y-cy)^2/b^2 = 1
```

rather than the original

```
x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1
```

The simple repair, I think, is to translate the line wrt `(cx,cy)` and translate the results back, like so:

```
...
double m = (in_y2-cy) - k*(in_x2-cx);
...
double ex1 = (-B1 + D/(2*A1)) + cx;
double ey1 = k*(ex1-cx) + m + cy;
double ex2 = (-B1 - D/(2*A1)) + cx;
double ey2 = k*(ex2-cx) + m + cy;
```

The more elegant repair is to solve the correct equation for the ellipse instead, but this results in even more impenetrable formulas for `B1` and `C1`:

```
double B1 = (2*k*(m-cy))/(b*b) - (2*cx)/(a*a);
double C1 = (m-cy)*(m-cy)/(b*b) - 1 + (cx*cx)/(a*a);
```

As a final remark, note that this breaks down for vertical lines, as then `r2 = 0` so `k` isn't defined.

Comment: There's an error in the parentheses in the ex equations. They should be `ex1 = (-B1 + D) / (2 * A1) + cx;` and `ex2 = (-B1 - D) / (2 * A1) + cx;`.

Answer (score 2):

Java can't solve the algebra problem, but it can compute the solution once you tell it what to compute.

Sounds like you just need to replace your `y` in the ellipse's equation with `kx+m` then solve for x. Looks like it's a simply binomial equation. Write a program that computes `x=...` based on k, m, a and b. Java can help you compute the roots if you tell it what to compute and what the values of k, m, a and b are.

In your particular case, you want to use Java as a simple calculator...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm doing that, but getting too big results.
I'm trying to find points of intersection, because I want to divide random ellipse by random line into two elliptic arcs. It's part of vector editor's functions that is my college project..

Answer (score 1):

can you please put your code so that we could see if it's correct?

anyway , here's an algorithm:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse-LineIntersection.html

note that since it has a square root , you might get a solution that is not precise.

Comment: The linked document uses a linear function, not an affine function for the line.

Comment: ok how about this: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?p=435345  or this : http://www.mombu.com/programming/delphi/t-calculate-ellipse-line-intersection-653276.html

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll go try that to see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: The first one uses the explicit form which is troubling OP, second one uses parameterized form which doesn't have that problem, but is quite roundabout.

Comment: Hm. Tried both and still think [this](http://i782.photobucket.com/albums/yy101/Cracked_Nut/troub.png) is the problem.

Comment: @genoxide You confused X and Y for the "Java coordinates". BTW there is nothing un-Cartesian to the Java coordinates. The only difference is that Y increases downwards, so it's a "left" coordinate system. But this is just a presentational detail -- the equations work in any case. Your statement would imply that you are not describing the line and the eclipse using the same coordinate system.

Comment: thanks for clarifying this issue , as i thought for a moment that i didn't understand him.

Comment: Lol, you are totally right. All messed up (:
Hm. If so, I can't even find the roots of problem. If it was "right" coordinate system, I guess I'd had to make transformations, but so..

Answer (score 0):

```
Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(x1,y1,x2,y2);

Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,width,height);

int resolution = 1000;
int x_distance = ellipse.getWidth()/2;
int y_distance = ellipse.getHeight()/2;

double angle = 360.0/(double)resolution;

Point center = new Point(width/2,height/2);
Point point = new Point();

for (int index = 0; index < resolution; index++)
{
    int x = (center.x+x_distance)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle*index)));
    int y = (center.y+y_distance)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle*index)));

    Ellipse2D.Double dot = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,1,1);

    if (line.intersects(dot.getBounds()))
    {
       point.setLocation(x,y);
       index = resolution;
    }
}
```